# Can I add a div with multiple images inside a Bootstrap carousel slide? If so, how do I do that?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a carousel slider on my HTML page and I'd like to make it so each slide is a div containing multiple images, something like this:

[image]

I've already tried adding this to each `carousel-item` div inside the carousel:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="d-block h-100">
        <img src="images/mario_strikers.jpg">
        <img src="images/mario_strikers.jpg">
        <img src="images/mario_strikers.jpg">
        <img src="images/mario_strikers.jpg">
        <img src="images/mario_strikers.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

but it didn't quite work and I'm not sure that's the right way either. Is it even possible? How could I do that?

Comment: And what if the 4 images have different aspect ratios?  Should they be cropped to fit 4 equal size rectangles or be scaled and of unequal size?  Anyway, you can do this using a Bootstrap grid inside each div.

Comment: Bootstrap no more supports carousel component my suggestion is to go with http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ documentation is very good to undertand and light weight you can play with many more options to make it look good

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to add multiple images to a Bootstrap carousel.

Take a look at the following example. I'm using the most basic [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#slides-only), sending a div with multiple child images. Then, to achieve the look on the example image, you would need to use a grid layout on the div.

Take a look at the following example:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap Carousel</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: beige;">
          <div class="row align-items-center" style="height: 100vh">
            <img class="col-sm-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/07/09/06/bridge-7504605__340.jpg" alt="...">
            <img class="col-sm-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/15/21/23/cat-7523894__340.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="col-sm-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/03/04/11/37/coast-6067736__340.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="col-sm-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/15/06/45/danube-river-7522608__340.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/24/16/32/bulldog-7476727__340.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/03/04/11/37/coast-6067736__340.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good start, but each div would also need Bootstrap grid layout to make it look like the example in the question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Yogi. My code is just to help point him in the right direction. A grid layout would be needed to get what is in the picture of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Ken Wheelers Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider to have better control over carousel slides responsively in Bootstrap 4.

For example in demo below we are showing...

- XS (smallest mobile first screen) - 3 images slides - 3 slides to scroll - no arrows
- SM (small screen) - 4 images slides - 4 slides to scroll - show arrows
- MD (medium screen) - 5 images slides - 5 slides to scroll - show arrows
- LG (large screen) - 6 images slides - 6 slides to scroll - show arrows
- XL (extra-large screen) - 7 images slides - 7 slides to scroll - show arrows

See live example demo below...

> All settings in list above are easily customisable for each bootstrap
> 4 breakpoint event via js options below...

```js
var breakpoint = {
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200
};

// slick slider
$('#slick').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  pauseOnFocus: false,
  draggable: true,
  infinite: true,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  speed: 1000,
  mobileFirst: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: breakpoint.sm,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        arrows: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        arrows: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.lg,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 6,
        arrows: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xl,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 7,
        arrows: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#slick {
  display: none;
}

#slick.slick-initialized {
  display: block;
}

#slick .slick-list {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

#slick .slick-slide {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#slick .slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
  cursor: grab;
}

#slick .slick-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 49px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 1000px;
}

#slick .slick-arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#slick .slick-arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slick .slick-prev {
  left: -30px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/ao7qeXi.png');
}

#slick .slick-next {
  right: -30px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/AhkEkP6.png');
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Slick CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div id="slick">

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JX3Ppxe.png" class="w-100 img-fluid" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slick jQuery min -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```